# python list of floats, sum is 1.0 but (sum(list) == 1.0) gives False. WHY?

Tags: python, floating-point, precision

In python:

```
>>> x = [0.287, 0.059, 0.118, 0.001, 0.001, 0.024, 0.307, 0.001, 0.201, 0.001]
>>> print sum(x)
    1.0
```

But:

```
>>> print sum(x) == 1.0
False
```

Why is floating point error causing this? can someone explain??

Comment: print more digits and you'll see that it's not really 1.0

Comment: `float.__str__` in Python 2 is not the same as, and apparently less precise than, `float.__repr__`. This was fixed in Python 3. Compare `str(sum(x))` (the result of which is used by `print`) and `repr(sum(x))` (the result of which is used if you simply type `sum(x)` at the prompt) in Python 2 and Python 3.